# Ethernet Calling on Android

Tags: ethernet

We've been using iPhones for as long as they've been out, but they've recently began blocking features that we use.  We're looking for a change.  Can you make calls and/or text via ethernet connection on an Android?

Comment: I assume you are referring to "Wifi Calling" and "SMS over Wifi". In that scenario "Wifi" means just any IP based network connection, so if you would use an USB Ethernet adapter (and a device that supports it) it should also work using Ethernet. Of course the device and your mobile network provider have to support both features.